# How to create a Drupal website using another Drupal backup?

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal project running on a server and I want to work on an exact copy of it, with the same content types and the same data in the database, etc., on my own computer so that I can do a troubleshooting and debugging sessions for errors etc. How can I do that?

I tried before to get a backup of the project database and used it to make a database, then I tried to install Drupal through the wizard, and at the next for the database through the wizard, I typed the same name as the database that I created using the backup files, but the wizard gave me the error that the database already exists and the installation did not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Install drupal locally as usual **without** your DB backup, use the same database name and passwords to make it easier.
Once you have a basic running drupal site, import your backup DB overwriting the DB of the newly installed site.
Copy the files folder from your live site to your local site.